# Fail to change the apps file permission on android 12

Tags: android, smartphone, android-settings

I don't know what is happening because it happened spontaneously. Some apps just lose their file permission and I cannot change it back. What is going wrong?

[The example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQQXf.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Example App: Random Slideshow. Transferred via Smartswitch from Android 11 phone to Android 12 phone. There it does not get access to microSD card's files even though it has media permissions.